# How to generate thumbnail images or GIFs from .GLB 3D models in Python?

Tags: model, 3d

I'm working on a project where I need to generate thumbnail images or GIFs from .GLB 3D models in Python. I'm looking for a library or function that can help me achieve this.

I have 3D models in the .GLB format, and I want to create thumbnail images or GIFs similar to the examples below:

examples:
[image]

[image]